# unable to use list in vector of list

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have made a vector of list of char

```
vector<list<char>> vect;
```

and i have to iterate though the vector to print all first elements of list. 
I have done

```
for (auto i = vect.begin(); i != vect.end(); i++)
    {
        cout<<*i.front();
    }
```

it is giving error that there is no function `.front()`
the complete error is below

```
error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::list<char> > >’ has no member named ‘front’
         cout << *i.front();
```

can anyone help me out for this error?

Comment: `(*i).front();` , see operator precedence [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Have you tried `i->front();`?

Comment: Also, check the size before accessing unless you're certain that none of the lists is empty.

Comment: [Your expression evaluates as `*(i.front())`, rather than `(*i).front()`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `(*i).front()`  and i->front both are working. and as I understand it is due to operator precedence. thank for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Line

```
cout<<*i.front();
```

the compiler tries to get the value at `( i.front() )`. So, you where getting the error iterator i does not have a member named front().

`i` -> iterator pointer
`*i` -> value at iterator list in this case

`i.front()` -> not a member of the iterator
`(*i).front()` -> front of list

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying is equivalent too

```
cout<<*(i.front());
```

`i` is an iterator so it doesn't have `front`.

You can simply use

```
cout<<i->front();
```